# How do I set a variable in a PHP page, pass it to a CSS file and assign it to a single CSS attribute?

Tags: php, javascript, css, variables

*First off, FYI: The .php file referenced below will be the index.php of a Serindipity blog, which is a very complex mess of code and files.*

In my index.php file, I want to grab the query string, if one exists, from the URL and assign it to a variable (as in **variable=self.location.search**).

I want to then assign that variable to a single attribute of a single entry in a style.css file that is called by one of the many files Serindipity utilizes to generate the ouptput page:

```
body {
font-size: 10pt;
margin: 1;
background-color: #000000;
font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

I want to change only the **background-color** parameter of one of the many entries, shown above, to the $ value of that variable (which would be either "**transparent**" or null).

In the process, I need to employ logic code to determine if there is a query string at all.

If yes, make **background-color=variable**. If not, make **background-color="#000000"**.

(Of course, the logic must be executed within the CSS file.)

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't change CSS files dynamically, but you can change the style attribute of the element(s) using JS. Try taking another approach.

Comment: Can you add some javascript to the page?

Comment: To which page? I think the answer is no, as one is a PHP page and the other is a CSS file.

Comment: You should be able to add Javascript to the PHP page, but if you're not sure how the output is generated (which seems to be the case) then maybe it's better to not change anything.

Comment: I tried to add js to the php page and it broke. Dreamweaver gave me syntax errors with every <script> tag and broke the rest of the page, and when I removed those it errored out on the js instructions (like "object.").

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the engine you mentioned (Serindipity), but this should be pretty straightforward, as long as you are allowed to create and edit your own Php-scripts (which really shouldn't matter as long the engine isn't dependent on the name of the `style-sheet`):

Change the file-ending of the style-sheet to

```
.php
```

and the webserver will recognize it as a php-script. Set the mime-type to text/css like @Brighty wrote

```
header('Content-type: text/css');
```

and the user will never know the difference (except, of course, the file-ending being `.php`).

If the style-sheet having a file-ending of `.php` is a problem, you can always use .htaccess and some clever regex to make the user believe they are seeing a `.css`.

**Edit:** Also, if you have access to configure what file/s will be recognized as php-scripts, you can set your server to also recognize `.css` as a php-file (which, as far as I know wouldn't be a problem, since php will just toss any plain text encountered out to the user).

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. And will all of the CSS instructions in the file still read the same, just as if it were still a .css file?

Comment: Of course. Do this as a proof of concept: Create a php-file, write the php start- and end-tags (write some expression between these if you want), and below the end-tags (or above the start-tags) write some text.

Comment: The text (plus the output of the expression, if you wrote any) will be tossed to the user as plain text (which will be rendered as usual by the user, in the case of e.g. html).

Comment: Ok, THANKS! Now the question becomes, what is the code I'll need to create the arguments, assign the variable, etc.? (as I don't code PHP!)

Comment: **That** is a whole other topic. Try [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_intro.asp), it might help you on the way.

Comment: Also, I need to know how to assign the variable to the value of the CSS property.

Comment: @JamesKotak you have two very clear and simple answers here, I would recommend actually writing some code to try it out yourself, hopefully you'll learn a thing or two.

Comment: If i knew how to write the code I wouldn't be here asking how to do it now, would I? Your comment is not helpful, Dunhamzzz.

Comment: @JamesKotak Read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), it clearly states that questions too broad is better suited elsewhere, or after an extended tutorial.

Comment: @JamesKotak Now, I know how frustrating it is to get an answer like that, but please understand, we are doing this on our spare time, and however much I would like to give you an in-depth tutorial, it is simply not possible, or even appropriate, on this site. So, before you ask any more questions, try going to the tutorial I linked, [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_syntax.asp), it's actually **very** helpful and not a little easy for the beginner :)

Comment: I have been looking though the page you linked too earlier and am now learning PHP! Thanks again.
Also, @Dunhamzzz: I apologize; I realize what you were saying now. I misunderstood your point. I wasn't taking into account the link Marcus gave me. My bad. Thanks to you both.

Comment: @JamesKotak Although it might feel offensive, I doubt it is. If you stay around here long enough, you might notice the "Write some code!"-idiom popular among programmers, it simply means that the only way to learn something is by getting downright dirty with code all the way down to your elbows! Anyway, hoped it helped :)

Comment: You helped out very much - thank you again. I appreciate the links too. I mastered BASIC 2.0 on the C=64 back in the 80s but haven't learned another language since. Now, as I look through the chapters in the PHP pages, I'm feeling the same excitement I experienced back in the day. A little kick in the butt is sometimes a very good thing! Thanks for the kick. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your file is a `.php` file and you can just use PHP in it like so:

```
<?php

$colour1 = isset($variable) ? $variable : '#000';

header("Content-Type: text/css");
?>

body {
    background: <?php echo $colour1; ?>
}

div {
    color: <?php echo $colour1; ?>
}
```

Obviously this is quite flexible! [Here's a link](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/csscolor/) I found extending the method even more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a CSS file. I am kind of stuck in that regard. I have to be able to dynamically change the value of the **background-color** property to the variable, and only if the variable = "transparent".

Answer (score 0):

you can't set any variable in the css file, jquery or javascript is the best option to play with your css file.

or you will do with inline css.

Comment: Well, can I set the variable in the php file (and perform the logic necessary determine what the variable value is to be) then employ the variable in the value of the property in the css file?

Comment: @JamesKotak as you said above you want to change the background-color property only if the variable is "transparent" right, then assign a variable in php and if the variable is true set the background-color into inline css with a property '!important', hope you understand

Comment: Yes, I do - thanks. Unfortunately, the CSS file will be called later on by one of the many complex files that make up the Serindipity blog application, which will override any inline instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve this by mixing css and php code in a single file with a php extension, and setting the mime type of the file to 'text/css'.

```
header('Content-type: text/css');
```

I have done a similar thing in ColdFusion but never in php so I can't guarantee this will work.

Comment: Thanks. This won't work for me, as I am bound by the structure of the Serindipity application. Changing the core structure would require basically rewriting portions of the most complex part of the code, and unfortunately I am a total n00b.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the only way I know to get conditional logic into a css file. It looks like changing the background colour with javascript is your best bet.

Comment: ...and there's no way to run a script within a CSS file, right?

Comment: Thanks Brighty... Marcus Hasson is expounding on this concept a littel more for me. Much appreciated!