# How to Get php variable to file?

Tags: php

I'm calling a PHP file in to my site like this as a CSS like below so I can get PHP variables to CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="templates/css/design.php?color=#ffffff" />
```

I can call variables which I define inside the **design.php** file but I can't call variables from out side the php file as I'm using it as a CSS file.

So I thought of passing the color with file name so I can make it editable.

Can anyone please tell me how I can get the color from this parameter from with in the php file?

```
?color=#ffffff"
```

Comment: You better explain the real task you're solving, not the broken "solution"

Comment: You might be interested in reading a bit of the PHP manual before asking: http://php.net/language.variables.external

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [*PHP Variables in the CSS Stylesheet*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17998676/367456) and [*How do I set a variable in a PHP page, pass it to a CSS file and assign it to a single CSS attribute?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8048617/367456)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php echo $_GET['color'];?>
```

you can use hidden field for send data to other pages  assign variable and also get from url.if suffering problem any type you can use jquery for assign value in color field.

Comment: I was able fix it by using some functionality from my CMS.. Anyways thanks guys... :)